# How to apply case when statement after group by clause

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, psql, case-when

**INPUT:**

I have a table which looks like:

```
    date   | is_shipped | is_realised | mrp  
----------+------------+-------------+------
 12022015 |          1 |           1 | 1000
 12022015 |          0 |           1 | 2000
 12022015 |          1 |           0 | 3000
 13022015 |          1 |           1 | 1500
 13022015 |          0 |           1 | 2500
 13022015 |          1 |           0 | 3500
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

I want to group the rows by date to get total mrp and also mrp corresponding to `is_shipped = 1` and `is_realised = 1`. Example, the total mrp on `12022015` is 1000 + 2000 + 3000 = 6000. Total mrp corresponding to `is_shipped = 1` on `12022015` is 1000 + 3000 = 4000. Total mrp corresponding to `is_realised = 1` on `12022015` is 1000 + 2000 = 3000.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

So, my result should look something like:

```
    date   | shipped_mrp | realised_mrp | mrp  
----------+-------------+--------------+------
 12022015 |        4000 |         3000 | 6000
 13022015 |        5000 |         4000 | 7500
```

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:**

I tried the following query, which does not work:

```
select sum(mrp),
CASE WHEN is_realised = 1
THEN 
    SUM(mrp)
ELSE
    0
END AS realised_mrp,
CASE WHEN is_shipped = 1
THEN 
    SUM(mrp)
ELSE
    0
END AS shipped_mrp
from rev
group by date;
```

**ERROR:**

I get the following error:

> column "rev.is_realised" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used
>   in an aggregate function LINE 2: CASE WHEN is_realised = 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the case statement inside the `sum` function:

```
select 
  date, 
  sum(CASE WHEN is_shipped = 1 THEN mrp ELSE 0 END) AS shipped_mrp,
  sum(CASE WHEN is_realised = 1 THEN mrp ELSE 0 END) AS realised_mrp,
  sum(mrp) AS mrp
from rev
group by date;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8622f/1)

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If using **PG9.4+** use the much more efficient `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT "date",
       sum(mrp) FILTER (WHERE is_shipped = 1) AS shipped_mrp,
       sum(mrp) FILTER (WHERE is_realised = 1) AS realised_mrp,
       sum(mrp) AS mrp
FROM rev
GrOUP BY 1;
```